# Почему модуль debug в Yii2 постоянно выдаёт Bad Request 400

Tags: yii2

В yii2 я открываю страницу, у которой через модуль debug вижу 8 ошибок (показано на скриншоте). При клике на них браузер слегка задумывается и вываливается ошибка Bad Request 400. При этом не понятно про какой именно id оно говорит - это первое. И второе то, что то, вывалившаяся страница тоже подгружает ещё один debug модуль (на скриншоте видно в самом низу картинки) и там уже 9 ошибок.

Поясню по поводу запросов. Это не аякс запросы. Это обычная страница списка моделей. Гридвью там обёрнут в Pjax. Как вы видите по урлу, запроса на что-либо с id нету - это список страниц. Хотя эта же ошибка у меня дублируется на всех страницах админки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может следующее уточнение поможет уточнить информацию... Админка, скриншот которой выше, у меня работает через модуль

```
'admin' => [
    'class' => 'app\modules\admin\Module',
    'layout' => 'main'
],
```

и работает она из папки

> \backend\modules\admin\views\site\

Так вот когда я нахожусь в админке, которая работает из модуля, то у меня везде Bad request или Not found.

Но если перейти в "родную" админку, которая по адресу

> \backend\views\site\

, то Bad request или Not found не наблюдается. Скриншот ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но таже самая ерунда, когда при клике на debag модуль открывается не его содержимое, а вывалившаяся страница с ещё одним подгруженным debug модулем (на скриншоте видно в самом низу картинки) и если кликнуть его, то и следующая страница подтягивает новый debag и так до бесконечности, что и показано на скриншоте.

Вобщем, Bad request или Not found, думаю, как-то связаны с роутингом админок, а фрактальность - хз с чем.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как минимум посмотреть эти ошибки в логах, скорее всего там написано что не так......во-вторых обязательные параметры id - это то, что прилетает в экшн контроллера, а вы не передаёте своим запросом...скорее всего аяксом....а значит на JS не формируете правильный URL и id ......... в третьих когда рендерите страницу, то вы используете навернякак простой `render`, а нужно `renderAjax` или что-то типа того, т.к. запрос у вас аяксовский

Comment: я не думаю, что это касается id какого-то элемента из базы данных и запроса к нему

Comment: *"Это не аякс запросы. Это обычная страница списка моделей. Гридвью там обёрнут в Pjax."*  --- ясно понятно.... А теперь идите читать, что такое PJAX .......не аякс запросы у него...))

Comment: А не работает админка из модуля скорее всего из-за кривой маршрутизации и неправильно настроенного модуля

Comment: с точки зрения банальной эрудиции, такую помощь тоже можно назвать помощью. Благодарю, очень помог!

Comment: когда я открываю дебаг в соседнем вкладке /backend/web/debug/default, то он работает нормально, нареканий нет, а вот на текущей странице фрактальность сохраняется. Я перенёс админку из модуля admin в стандартный SiteController, вообще отключил использование modules, ошибка с id пропала, но фрактальность осталась

Comment: С точки зрения банальной эрудиции, выучил бы значение слова "фрактальность", прежде чем его пихать везде, где не попадя.

Comment: Лёш, спасибо, помог неоценимо, советы просто гениальные! Всё по делу, всё по делу! В точку всё! Вот взял и решил!